# Using voters on silex

Tags: silex

I've been looking around for documentation or even examples of using voters on silex. However, there is not a lot out there.

Is there any good example of voters being used on silex 1.*? Or even documentation?

Comment: You should narrow your question... The [```isGranted```](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#checking-user-roles) method uses voters. Are you talking about custom voters? Can you clarify your needs with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no documentation dedicated on how to use voters in Silex projects. But it is quite simple to add your own voters just by overriding the [`security.voters`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L142) array :

```
use Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider;

$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider());

$app['security.voters'] = $app->share($app->extend('security.voters', function ($voters, $app) {
    $voters[] = new MyVoter();

    return $voters;
}));
```